# Marginals and compactness in the narrow topology

Tags: probability, reference-request, measure-theory

I've read in a [working paper](http://econ.jhu.edu/wp-content/uploads/pdf/papers/wp585_khan.pdf) (bottom of page 9) that the following is a "standard result":

> Let $A$ be a compact metric space and $T$ be a Polish space. 
>    Let $\rho$ be a Borel probability measure on $T$. Let
>   $\mathcal{M}^\rho(T\times A)$ be the set of Borel probability measures
>   on $T\times A$ such that the marginal on $T$ is equal to $\rho$. Then
>   $\mathcal{M}^\rho(T\times A)$ is a compact set in the narrow topology on the space of probability measures.

Could anyone tell me how to show this or give me a reference? The narrow topology is the same as the weak* topology or the topology of weak convergence of measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $T$ is separable and complete, by Ulam's theorem, for each $j\geq 1$, we can find a compact subset of $T$, say $K_j$, such that $\rho(K_j)\geq 1-j^{-1}$. If $P\in \mathcal M^{\rho}(T\times A)$, then 
$$P(K_j\times A)=\rho(K_j)\geq 1-j^{-1}.$$
As $K_j\times A$ is a compact subset of $T\times A$, the set $\mathcal M^{\rho}(T\times A)$ is uniformly tight. By of Prokhorov theorem, as $T\times A$ is separable and complete, $\mathcal M^{\rho}(T\times A)$ has a compact closure in the narrow topology. As this one is metrizable, to see that $\mathcal M^{\rho}(T\times A)$ is closed, we just have to check sequential closeness. Let $\{ P_n\}\subset \mathcal M^{\rho}(T\times A)$ converging in law to $P$. We just have to show that for each open set $O$ of $S$, $P(O\times A)=\rho(O)$. We have by portmanteau theorem, 
$$P(O\times A)\leq \liminf_n P_n(O\times A)=\rho(O).$$
As a closed set in a metric space is a countable intersection of open sets, we have $P(O^c\times A)\leq \rho(O^c)$, so $\rho(O)=P(O\times A)$ for all open set $O$.

---

> **Theorem.(Ulam)** Let $(S,d)$ a complete separable metric space. Then each Borel probability measure on $S$ is tight.

*Proof:* Let $\{x_n\}$ a sequence dense in $S$, and $\varepsilon>0$. For each $j$, let 
$N_j$ integer such that $P\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^{N_j}B(x_l,j^{-1})\right)\geq 1-2^{-1}\varepsilon$. Then $K:=\bigcap_{j\geq 1}\overline{\bigcup_{l=1}^{N_j}B(x_l,j^{-1})}$ is pre-compact and closed, hence compact, and $P(K)\geq 1-\varepsilon$.

> **Theorem.(Prokhorov)** Let $(S,d)$ a separable metric space, and $\mathcal P$ a family of Borel probability measures. If $\mathcal P$ is uniformly tight, that is, for all $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a compact subset $K$ of $S$ such that for each element $P$ of $\mathcal P$, $P(K)\geq 1-\varepsilon$, then $\mathcal P$ is relatively compact for the narrow topology.

Comment: In the first version, I forget to check that $\mathcal M^{\rho}$ is closed for the narrow topology.

Comment: The Prokhorov theorem as stated is valid without the assumption that $S$ is separable. This assumption is needed for the converse statement, namely that a relatively compact set is tight.

Comment: @Ahriman Yes, the fact that $T\times A$ is Polish gives us that the narrow topology is metrizable (that what is needed here). And you are right, this direction of Prokhorov theorem doesn't need separability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm also looking for a reference for this. Can anyone provide a reference?